# In which case we define only one member in enum in C?

Tags: c++, c, enums

I saw some code like this:

```
enum
{
   FIRST_DAY = 0
};
```

I know the grammar allows only one member in the enum, but in which case we define it like this? and what is the reason?

Comment: maybe enhanced readibility? future expansion support?

Comment: The answer is very different in C and C++, which do you want?

Comment: any of it, I am newbie in C and C++

Comment: There's also `struct Foo{};` which may seem useless, but it certainly isn't. There's practically always someone who has a valid use case for it, but listing all cases is basically impossible, and asking for some cases is asking for opinion, hence OT (imo).

Comment: @TartanLlama How is it very different?

Comment: @PeterSchneider one-member enums are often used in C++ for getting around `static const` member restrictions, especially when defining metafunctions. This is not the case in C. I guess *very different* is hyperbolic, but still.

Comment: @TartanLlama Don't forget `constexpr` ;-)

Comment: Some compilers, in debug mode, will provide identifier names for `enum` types but not for `#define`.  Primarily because the `#define` are inserted (replaced) before the compiler knows the identifier name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess, but in C this was an idiom to define named integer constants without resorting to using #define.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to do it like this instead of having #define FIRST_DAY 0.
Also it's now possible to extend it if necessary.

Comment: why it is better to do it like this? why not define constant?

Comment: There are many reasons. The most important one from my point of view is that using preprocessor symbols can make it much harder to debug.